Watched Tags is no longer accessible from the home page
The proposed design for the homepage update shows three widgets, including a Watched Tags widget.
BUG:  The Watched Tags widget doesn't appear.

This may seem low priority, but other aspects of the new design make direct access to the tag watchlist (and ignore list) from the home page absolutely essential.
Despite claims of personalizing the list based on the watchlist and history, the feed is mostly questions that aren't relevant to either.  Yet the homepage feed no longer highlights questions with watched tags, so it's now impossible to scan for questions that are likely to be of interest.
The apparent workaround is to add (possibly many) tags to the ignore list, yet there's no longer direct access to the Watched Tags list from the home page.  I had three tags on my ignore list.  I added at least 40 more on the first day of the new design to get the feed filtered enough to be able to spot some of the questions that should have just been highlighted.
The old design had direct access to both Watched Tags and Ignored Tags in the side bar, using versions of the widget that actually showed far more tags than the new low-content-density one that was supposed to be highlighted at the top of the new feed.  Furthermore, the old widgets let you edit the lists without leaving the context of the feed one is trying to filter.
To add tags to ignore, one must first go to their profile page (which also feature the widgets for reputation and badge chasing), and then to "Edit profile" and then click on the "Tag watching & ignoring", and then scroll down to the "Ignored tags" list, and then click "Add a tag".
That's five clicks to start adding tags.  Two of those clicks ("Tag watching & ignoring" and "Add a tag" have no visual affordance, and the latter is low contrast.)

I do have the watched tags widget on my home page though?

I do see "watched tags" at the top of the page.

Can't repro.

This is due to browser viewport width - the 'widgets' are a fixed size, and we drop one out when 3 won't fit side-by-side. We have more work coming in this area - possibly the ability to scroll between them, as well as being able to actually personalise by choosing which widgets are actually relevant to you.

O.O... so when choosing a widget to get rid of to make space we got rid of the only one that's useful...

@cart:  It's a Chrome window at 1920 wide so I can fit two apps side-by-side on the monitor.  The screen shot was taking at 110% zoom (which is the bare minimum I can tolerate for Stack Overflow).  But even if I drop it to 100%, I still get just two widgets.  Given how the tag watch and ignore lists are now absolutely critical to making the page useful, perhaps it should be given priority over one of the other widgets.

I won't say I necessarily agree with the prioritisation, but there's a balance being struck across the userbase I believe. The work to bring in customisation (or at least some form of scrolling) should be a fast follow.

@cart: "Balance ... across the userbase" seems weird for a design update aimed at personalizing the home page.  Given how many concerns were raised, perhaps there could be an escape hatch for people to opt-out while this is still in beta.  I wish my user profile had an option to select which view I want as my home page.

How do I hide all these stupid widgets? They take up far too much room, including the waste of space above it welcoming me. Whose idea was this useless change?

I don't like the new design at all. It is distracting, the widgets take up way too much space (half my desktop screen, and more than a full screen on mobile), and the watch list is harder for me to access on a desktop screen (it is fine on secondary pages, where the list is still on the sidebar and full length without scrolling). I have 22 watched tags that I jump between frequently, so anything that makes that harder is not good for me. I have a hard enough time using watched tags on a mobile browser (ie, I have to type them in manually), I don't need a desktop browser giving me trouble too.

"This is due to browser viewport width" Huh, seems like a good reason to make use of all that all that unnecessary unused space, @cart . Then the width issue would be less an issue, you'd have more width to "play" with.

This is all useful stuff peeps - we do plan to iterate on this design, and will be looking to provide much more control over your own experience (I know that sounds like more stupid corporate speak but we genuinely want you to be able to make this page work for the way you use the site). Like, hiding the widgets if you feel strongly enough about that (thus taking it virtually back to the old view) or have them show in the right sidebar instead, that sort of thing.

Well those concerns where already mentioned in the announcement post. As a lot of comments/answers over there already mentioned that most of the feedback wasn't taken into account. Feels like working in circles.

This is easily reproduced when zooming in.

Can we call this irresponsive design?

@cart: If the plan is to iterate and see what works for people, then it shouldn't be unilaterally pushed to the entire userbase.  It's the home page for crying out loud!  If the goal is personalization, then the first step is enabling user customization.  From there, you can play with how to choose the default configuration and try to tune up a recommendation engine.  If the goal is getting new users to be more interactive, then controlled experiments (A/B testing) on newly created accounts will give you actual data on what works and what doesn't.  Opt-in betas for everyone else, please.

Just use https://stackoverflow.com/questions as the main page (until they break that one too). The new one is just unusable.

@cart Have you done any user research? Has any user requested anything in the new design? Or did someone who never used the site do the design?

Alright folks, valid opinions all round. I'm going to stick an id on the top elements to allow you to hide the new stuff if you're desperate to do so...plus I'll let you in on a little secret, if you include ?tab=<one of the old tabs> ('hot', 'interesting' etc) in the URL, it's an escape hatch to the old homepage. OBVIOUS CAVEAT - we won't be supporting that page going forward, and it will be turned off at some point. In the meantime, if that helps you while we iterate on the new homepage, have at it.

Wait, now the Watched Tags box is gone from the question page too - what happened?

@MathiasR.Jessen still there for me. Maybe an A/B test?

@cart:  When you say you won't be supporting "the old homepage" going forward, are you referring to stackoverflow.com/questions or stackoverflow.com?tab=<one of the old tabs>?

@AdrianMcCarthy /questions is not the home page, just / is. So, it's the latter that won't be supported in the future.

Why are questions with my watched tags no longer highlighted on the new home page? I gives me a headache trying to search through the list for my tags to find relevant questions. It is so much more user-friendly (and just enjoyable to use) when my watched tags ARE highlighted for me. Can this be fixed? They are highlighted on the Newest Questions page. Which I now have to keep in the copy-buffer to return to a usable StackOverflow list. Clicking on the icon (top-left) takes me to the unwanted new page without watched-tags highlighted.
